# Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'newRow' was corrupted

Tags: c++, arrays, c, char, stack

I've still getting an error of how the stack around `newRow` is tried using `strncat()` so that I can say how many new charters that where added to the string, but in the end I still have a corruption around `newRow`.

In terms of a variables being passed into this function, I think they are pretty straight forward. I also use `sizeOfString` as a custom made function because I'm not allowed to use the standard `sizeof` function.

```
char* makeRow(char elementOne[20], int elementNumber, int numCycles, int orginalData[40], float ctValues[7]){
    char newRow[] = "";
    int lookingAt;
    int dataPoint;
    char* elementPtr;
    int charArrSize;

    elementNumber = elementNumber--;

    elementPtr = elementOne;
    int lenOfElemnt = *(&elementOne + 1) - elementOne;

    //charArrSize = sizeOfString(elementPtr);
    charArrSize = sizeOfString(elementOne);
    strncat(newRow, elementOne, charArrSize);
    //strcpy(csvThirdRow, (",%s", elementOne));
    for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
    {
        lookingAt = (((i - 1) * 5) + 1 - 1);
        int maxLookingAt = numCycles * 5;
        dataPoint = orginalData[lookingAt];
        char dataPointBuffer[100];

        if (lookingAt < maxLookingAt)
        {
            sprintf(dataPointBuffer, ",%d", dataPoint);
            charArrSize = sizeOfString(dataPointBuffer);
            strncat(newRow, dataPointBuffer, charArrSize);
        }
        else
        {
            strncat(newRow, ",",1);
        }
    }

    char ctBuffer[20];
    float ctNumber = ctValues[elementNumber];

    sprintf(ctBuffer, ",%.2f\n", ctNumber);
    charArrSize = sizeOfString(ctBuffer);
    strncat(newRow, ctBuffer, charArrSize);

    return newRow;
}
```

Comment: Please provide complete code that can reproduce the problem. See: [mre].

Comment: `char newRow[] = "";` That is a one byte array. The only string it can store is the empty one. So trying to copy a non-empty string into it with `strncpy` causes buffer overflow and results in undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

If we omit the array dimension, compiler computes it for us based on the size of initialiser.

So, this

```
char newRow[] = "";
```

is same as this

```
char newRow[1] = "";
```

The size of `newRow` array is `1`.

You are trying to copy more than `1` character to `newRow` array which is leading to undefined behaviour and resulting in corruption.

From [strncat()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strncat):

> The behavior is undefined if the destination array does not have enough space for the contents of both dest and the first count characters of src, plus the terminating null character....

May you should try giving enough size to `newRow` array, like this

```
char newRow[1024] = {0};
```

There is another problem in your code -

You are returning the address of local variable `newRow`<sup>1)</sup> from `makeRow()` function. Note that  a local(automatic) non-static variable lifetime is limited to its scope i.e. the block in which it has been declared. Any attempt to access it outside of its lifetime lead to undefined behaviour.

Couple of things that you can do to fix it:
Either make `numRow` array `static` or declare `numRow` as `char *` type and allocate memory dynamically to it and, in this case, make sure to `free` it once done with it.

---

1). An expression that has type *array of type* is converted to an expression with type *pointer to type* that points to the initial element of the array object [there are few exceptions to this rule].